# Insertar objeto en datatables

Tags: datatables

Para crear/declarar el datatable.

Como se va a observar la 2da y 3er columna son arreglos de objetos, los cuales quiero mostrar el resultado un *string* separado por comas y otro por punto y coma.

Los tengo de esta manera puesto que al construir la tabla me traigo un json desde el servidor.

```
tablaSanciones = $('#tablaSanciones').DataTable({
  'destroy': true,
  'processing': true,
  'ordering': false,
  data: constr,
  "columns": [
  {
    "data": "tipoFalta"
  },
  {
    "data": "tipo_sancion[,].idTipoSancion"
  },
  {
    "data": "tipo_sancion[; ].sancion.valor",
  },
  ],
});
```

Para insertar construyo un objeto de la siguiente manera:

```
var aval = new Object();
aval.tipoFalta = $('#mdlCmbFalta').val();
aval.idTipoSancion = sancionArr;
aval.tipo_sancion = nomSancionArr;
var rowNode = tablaSanciones.row.add(aval).draw().node();
```

Al hacer el *insert* a la tabla una vez construida no reconoce la 2da y 3er columna, puesto que el nombre del objeto que construyo no compete al que me traigo desde base de datos.

Solucioné un campo haciendo esto:

```
var nomSancionArr = [
    {
        "sancion": {                
            "valor": nomSancion
        }
    }
];
```

Pero como pueden ver solo queda en la 3er columna, no puedo hacer lo mismo con la 2da por que el objeto "madre" por así decirlo se llama "tipo_sancion".

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo o hay algún tipo de alias o algo así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes concatenar tus dos arreglos en un solo objeto:

```
   var  tipoSancionArr = [
      {
        "idTipoSancion": idTipoSancion,
        "sancion": {
          "valor": nomSancion
        }
      }
    ];
```

Tus datos en objeto a agregar

```
var aval = new Object();
aval.tipoFalta = $('#mdlCmbFalta').val();
aval.tipo_sancion = tipoSancionArr;
var rowNode = tablaSanciones.row.add(aval).draw().node();
```